# Percentage increase in the length of pendulum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

I'm struggling with a physics question :

What should be the percentage increase in the length of the chord of a pendulum for the period increased by 1%?

The answer is 2%.

I tried with $w = 2 \pi/T = \sqrt{ g/L}$ but no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What percentage should you increase the area of a square box to increase its side length by 1%?

It's not 1%. Imagine you successfully increase the side length by 1%. Then because area is the square of side length, it increased by a factor $1.01^2 = 1.0201$, or roughly 2%. You must increase the area by 2% to increase the side length by 1%.

Similarly, the length of a pendulum is proportional to the square of its period. (Work this out from the algebra equation you gave.) So length of a pendulum is analogous to area of a box, and period of a pendulum is analogous to side length of a box. Just as with the box, increase one by 2% to increase the other by 1%.

Note that this is an approximation, not an exact result.

This problem is an example of two ideas you should learn well:

- [scaling laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_law)
- [binomial approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_approximation) (here with $\alpha = 1/2$)

Comment: Why do you increase by a factor 1.01^2 and not 1^2?

Comment: Do you know what percentages are?

Comment: @JustinD., 1% is 0.01.  If you *increase* something by 1%, the new value is 1.01 (101%) times the old value.

Comment: I feel really stupid :S